# Determine whether player character is at rest on static node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

TL;DR I would like to know how to determine whether my sprite character is at rest/still to determine if they can jump or not. The player is a 2D sprite with a physicsBody, but the `isResting` property is false in the majority of calls to `update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)` and I cannot figure out why.

Here is what I have tried:

`SKPhysicsContactDelegate` doesn't seem to work because it appears that it is for two dynamic objects. I am trying to determine whether a the player (dynamic) is at rest on some dynamic sprite (platform, ground, etc.)

I would think this would be possible with simply reading the `isResting` property, but it is only true ~1/30 called to the frame update.

Below is my code for setting up these physics bodies

```swift
let groundNode = Ground(size: groundSize) // Ground is just wrapper class for loading a sprite
groundNode.position.y = (-size.height/2) + groundSize.height * 8
groundNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: groundSize)
groundNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0001
groundNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
groundNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

playerNode = Player(name: "Player") // Player is just a wrapper class for loading a sprite
playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: self.size)
playerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0001
playerNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
playerNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
playerNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0.8
```

Outside of the `SKPhysicsBody` setup, I animate the sprite continuously. Even stopping and preventing the animation doesn't appear to affect the state of `isResting` and the `velocity` property has a very small `dy` (2.50663077849822e-07) sometimes

How can I determine whether this dynamic sprite is at rest on the static sprite? My area of interest is shown in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You could try testing if the `velocity` is less than a small value (your choosing), then set it to zero, this may trigger 
`isResting` to change.